# Different screen based on user role not working

Tags: firebase, flutter

Hi I'am new to Flutter making an app for booking appointments which require to screens for two types of users i.e. patient and doctor.

```
 class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  UserProvider userProvider;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
  await userProvider.refreshUser();

  _authMethods. getUserDetails();

});
}


  User user = User();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (user.role == 'patient') {
        return PatientHomePage();
      }
      else if (user.role == 'doctor') {
        return DoctorHomePage();}
      return Container(color: Colors.red,);
  }
}
```

role variable is defined in another dart file:

```
class User {   String uid;   String name;   String email;   String role = "patient";   String profilePhoto;    User({     this.uid,     this.name,     this.email,     this.role,     this.profilePhoto,   });   ........... }
```

the default value "patient" is assigned to it when a user logs in. `Future<void> addDataToDb(FirebaseUser currentUser) async {      User user = User(         uid: currentUser.uid,         email: currentUser.email,         name: currentUser.displayName,         profilePhoto: currentUser.photoUrl,         role: "patient");      firestore         .collection(USERS_COLLECTION)         .document(currentUser.uid)         .setData(user.toMap(user));   }` all this is happening in another dart file

But this logic is not working as expected as it's showing only the red screen on phone which implies that
there is some issue in getting user.role from firebase.
Please help me...

Comment: I don't see you are setting the `role` variable anywhere for this new `User` object which you created here `User user = User();`.

Comment: role variable is defined in another dart file``

Comment: `class User {
  String uid;
  String name;
  String email;
  String role = "patient";
  String profilePhoto;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.role,
    this.profilePhoto,
  });

 ...........
}
`

Comment: yes, it must be defined in the `User` model file right? But you need to assign a value to it. Where are you assigning a value to it?

Comment: the default value "patient" is assigned to it when a user logs in. `Future<void> addDataToDb(FirebaseUser currentUser) async {

    User user = User(
        uid: currentUser.uid,
        email: currentUser.email,
        name: currentUser.displayName,
        profilePhoto: currentUser.photoUrl,
        role: "patient");

    firestore
        .collection(USERS_COLLECTION)
        .document(currentUser.uid)
        .setData(user.toMap(user));
  }` all this is happening in another dart file.

Comment: @AmanSharma try with user = await _authMethods. getUserDetails();, if it will not work try with future builder. I

Comment: @AmanSharma you need to include these code parts into the question itself for better readability.

Comment: @ShaktiS.P.Swain it did not worked with await. i'm new with future builder can you tell how?

Answer (score 1):

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
 UserProvider userProvider;
 final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();
 User user = User();

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
     userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);
/// This method is future method so it might happen that after widget render you are getting response.
     await userProvider.refreshUser();

/// seState will rebuild your widget with new user details
     setState(() {
       user = _authMethods. getUserDetails();
     });

   });
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (user.role == 'patient') {
     return PatientHomePage();
   }
   else if (user.role == 'doctor') {
     return DoctorHomePage();}
   return Container(color: Colors.red,);
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting an error that "A value of type 'Future<User>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'. "

Comment: I would like to add that getUserDetails() contains `Future<User> getUserDetails() async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await _userCollection.document(currentUser.uid).get();

    return User.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data);
  }`

Comment: @AmanSharma  Is _authMethods. getUserDetails(); is a future method? If yes then put await before it.